# Renormalization of irrelevant operator in the effective field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I have some troubles in understanding the renormalization of the irrelevant operators in the effective field theory approach.

In the standard approach, one usually writes down the most general Lagrangian with all kinds of possible relevant/marginal/irrelevant operators. All these operators will be renormalized as the energy scale changes. However, in practice, the renormalization of the irrelevant operators (say, 6-vertex, 8-vertex, ...) can be quite complicated.

My question is whether the perturbation theory breaks down or not if one just renormalizes the relevant/marginal operators while leaves the irrelevant operators as their bare values measured at a high-energy scale. What if the bare values of these irrelevant operators are quite small (namely the dimensionless amplitudes of these operators are much smaller than one)?